# How to fix command line parameters changing when after reading another parameter?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a command-line program in `C89` that reads a file, applies changes on it and then save it. The file handling thing works fine (until now at least), but I'm struggling with reading the parameters. There are 3 parameters:

- input file,
- desired operation and
- output file.

When it reads these parameters, they are copied into a char array to be handled later in the code. When debugging step by step (I'm currently using `QtCreator`), the first parameter is copied fine (example: "`test.txt`"), but when I read the second one (the operation) the first parameters turns into "`\000est.txt`" (this is how it shows in debugger). Of course, if I use it as is I'll get a segmentation fault. I'm re-learning C so I'm still trying to get used to these things again.

I tried to make a copy to another `char array (strcpy(newstring, input);)`, and prevented the problem, but doesn't seems to be a good workaround. I'd try to avoid workarounds here.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 3)
    {
        printf("\nERROR: input needs to be at least <input file> <operation> <output file>. Exiting...");
        return -1;
    }
    char input[20];
    char option[6];
    char output[20];

    strcpy(input, argv[1]);
    strcpy(option, argv[2]);
    strcpy(output, argv[3]);

    //the file reading code is not here in main

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the input to be a filename ("`test.txt`") but I got a "`\000est.txt`" when copying the second argument into another `char array`.

Comment: If the command line arguments are longer than the provided arrays a buffer overflow will happen. And for the length don't forget the final 0-byte.

Comment: `argc` is the number of valid elements in the `argv` array, *including* `argv[0]`. So if your program is expected to take three arguments, then `argc` must be at least `4`.

Comment: Also remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That means a string of e.g. six characters needs space for *seven* to include the null-terminator.

Comment: Lastly, besides the problem with `argc` (and possible array overflows), the code you show should not exhibit any problems. The possible problems you have is most likely in the code you *don't* show. Please try to create a [mcve] that exhibits the problem to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You rarely need to copy command line arguments; just pass pointers to them.

Comment: The initial `if` is to check if there are 3 or less elements, it'll leave.

I'll put some tests to make sure the argument is valid... I didn't remember the null-terminated thing with `char` arrays :(

Comment: the code I didn't show was a `fp = fopen(input, "r+");` I made for testing but since the `input` argument was incorrect it'll give me a segmentation fault

Comment: Well, the null-terminating thing is correct. I made all char arrays larger by 1 and they worked.

Also, I'll look into using pointers instead of copying where applicable. Thanks people!